IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
I use this rsync to synchronize drives over the internet using this command, from a remote Linux machine to a local macOS machine:
sudo rsync -e 'ssh -p 8023 -i /path/to/key' -avxW --progress --delete \
         --exclude folders/to/exclude \
username@domain.myddns.me:/mnt/RemoteDriveName/ /Volumes/LocalDriveName

The command copies the files I need but fails to delete some files at the destination. It shows an error without details:
IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion

I already included option -v to increase verbosity; how can I trace the error or otherwise fix the command to also delete files?

Did it actually copy the files it needs to? This is usually because rsync failed to read a file or directory earlier in the job (permissions, or possibly issues with it being in-use/written to). You probably don't want it to delete files in the destination just because it couldn't be opened on the source, but you can use --ignore-errors to override. You can add more verbosity like -vv, but the error should be visible without it (try -q to only show errors)

Try adding -q to only show errors in the output, then either fix the file permissions or exclude the files/directories from the sync for each of those entries.

That was the issue: some files were giving an IO error (lost+found on Linux, .Trashes on macOS). I excluded all folders that caused errors  and now the command works and deletes files.
